# Search which table updated in legacy dts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dts

I have a list of legacy dts in sql server 2008,
I am looking for dts that updating/inserts rows to certain table.
There is any way to do it?
maybe with text search?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DTS packages are stored in the `msdb` database, in table `sysdtspackages`. If you look at the table structure, you'll see a column named `packagedata` of type `image`, which I believe is where the information that you're looking for is stored.

However, since that information is stored as binary data (a COM structure, I believe), a text search is obviously out of the question. There are probably ways to extract that information and dig into it, but I personally haven't ever had to do this myself.